# Facebook Realtime updates Tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, real-time-updates

I'm trying to add realtime updated to my facebook page programmatically. I already subscribed to realtime updates and now I'm trying to add realtime updates tab to my facebook page.
I'm calling

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&app_id=APP_ID&method=post`

but I keep getting `(#10) Application does not have permission for this action`.
My app has manage_pages and read_stream permissions. I'm assuming I'm missing other kind of permissions? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a _page_ access token?

Comment: I tried with that but I get this message `A user access token is required to request this resource`.

Comment: What? No, that’s totally against what the docs say: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime Could you try it in Graph API Explorer as shown there (copy&paste your page access token into the input field on top).

Comment: I am getting the same thing ... (#10) Application does not have permission for this action
I am following the facebook instructions exactly and I am using a page access token. There is no mention in the documentation anywhere that I could see referencing required application permissions. 
Any further thoughts on this?